# Why does this take more byte?

Tags: sketch

I am only replacing a portion of my code where I want to use the first method but as you can see it is making my sketch size little bigger

```c
//if(iBPM >= 40 || iBPM <= 170 )
      {
      char iBPMwav[50];
      String thisString = String(iBPM);
      String stringThree =  "n" + thisString;
      stringThree =  stringThree + ".wav";
      stringThree.toCharArray(iBPMwav, 50); 
      tmrpcm.play(iBPMwav);   
      }
```

**`Sketch uses 29678 bytes (100%)`**

This is simple but at the end, I want to go from the number 40 up to 170, and this is why I want to use the first method.

```c
//if(iBPM >= 40 || iBPM <= 170 )
  {
      if(iBPM == 71)
tmrpcm.play("n71.wav"); 
  else if(iBPM == 72)
tmrpcm.play("n72.wav");
  else if(iBPM == 73)
tmrpcm.play("n73.wav");  
  else if(iBPM == 74)
tmrpcm.play("n74.wav");     
  else if(iBPM == 75)
tmrpcm.play("n75.wav"); 
  else if(iBPM == 76)
tmrpcm.play("n76.wav"); 
  else if(iBPM == 77)
tmrpcm.play("n77.wav"); 
  else if(iBPM == 78)
tmrpcm.play("n78.wav"); 
  else if(iBPM == 79)
tmrpcm.play("n79.wav"); 
  else if(iBPM == 80)
tmrpcm.play("n80.wav"); 
  else if(iBPM == 81)
tmrpcm.play("n81.wav");
  else if(iBPM == 82)
tmrpcm.play("n82.wav");  
  else if(iBPM == 83)
tmrpcm.play("n83.wav");     
  else if(iBPM == 84)
tmrpcm.play("n84.wav"); 
  else if(iBPM == 85)
tmrpcm.play("n85.wav"); 
  else if(iBPM == 86)
tmrpcm.play("n86.wav"); 
  else if(iBPM == 87)
tmrpcm.play("n87.wav"); 
  else if(iBPM == 89)
tmrpcm.play("n89.wav");
  else if(iBPM == 90)
tmrpcm.play("n90.wav");
  else if(iBPM == 91)
tmrpcm.play("n91.wav"); 
  else if(iBPM == 92)
tmrpcm.play("n92.wav");
  else if(iBPM == 93)
tmrpcm.play("n93.wav");  
  else if(iBPM == 94)
tmrpcm.play("n94.wav");     
  else if(iBPM == 95)
tmrpcm.play("n95.wav"); 
  else if(iBPM == 96)
tmrpcm.play("n96.wav"); 
  else if(iBPM == 97)
tmrpcm.play("n97.wav"); 
  else if(iBPM == 98)
tmrpcm.play("n98.wav"); 
  else if(iBPM == 99)
tmrpcm.play("n99.wav");
  else if(iBPM == 100)
tmrpcm.play("n100.wav"); 
  else if(iBPM == 101)
tmrpcm.play("n101.wav"); 
  else if(iBPM == 102)
tmrpcm.play("n102.wav");                                                     
else 
 tmrpcm.play("n170.wav");
}
```

**`Sketch uses 29024 bytes (101%)`**

Comment: You are using the String class which is pretty mighty and not light weight. It is always a good idea NOT to use the String class on MCUs.

Comment: Are you aware that `iBPM >= 40 || iBPM <= 170` is always true?

Comment: @EdgarBonet No, `I didn't know`

Comment: Then you should learn what the operators `>=`, `<=` and `||` mean.

Comment: @EdgarBonet Yes I did look that up that after you mentioned and learned from somewhere else. Tell me about it what a huge mistake boy ha ha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest having simpler file names (same size, always 3 digit numbers)

```
/// Return a text "n000.wav" ... "n255.wav" 
/// depending on the parameter 
char* makeFileName(byte i) {    
  static char name[9] = "nxxx.wav";
  byte digit = i/100;
  name[1] = '0' + digit;
  i -= digit*100; 
  digit = i/10;
  name[2] = '0' + digit; 
  i -= digit*10;
  name[3] = '0' + i;

  return name;
}
```

Comment: Looks smart to me. I will try it today.

Comment: Alright, I like your idea.. changing the name of the files will be like loosen flywheel for me. Instead, I made your code into two versions the first for `"nxx.wav"` and one for `"nxxx.wav"`

Answer (score 1):

While the Strings class makes a C/C++ program easy to understand and maintain, as stated in the comments, using the Strings class is a memory intensive option which should be should be avoided when memory is in short supply.  Such as on the embedded processors used in most Arduino platforms.

Here are 2 examples where Stings is used and not used.  Note the reduction from 2326 bytes to 734 bytes of program memory necessary to store the sketch in the embedded processor.

```
void setup() 
{
}

void loop() 
{
  uint8_t iBPM;
  uint8_t pointer;
  for(iBPM = 40; iBPM <= 170; iBPM++)
  {
    char iBPMwav[50];
    String thisString = String(iBPM);
    String stringThree =  "n" + thisString;
    stringThree =  stringThree + ".wav";
    stringThree.toCharArray(iBPMwav, 50); 
//  tmrpcm.play(iBPMwav);   
  }
}
```

Sketch uses 2326 bytes (7%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32256 bytes. Global variables use 27 bytes (1%) of dynamic memory...

```
void setup() 
{
}

void loop() 
{
  uint8_t iBPM;
  uint8_t pointer;
  for(iBPM = 40; iBPM <= 170; iBPM++)
  {
    char iBPMwav[50];
    pointer = 0;
    char temp_str[10];
//  String thisString = String(iBPM);
//  String stringThree =  "n" + thisString;
//  stringThree =  stringThree + ".wav";
//  stringThree.toCharArray(iBPMwav, 50); 
    itoa(iBPM, temp_str, 10);
    if(iBPM < 100)
    {
      strncpy(&iBPMwav[pointer],"n0",2);
      pointer += 2;
      strncpy(&iBPMwav[pointer],temp_str,2);
      pointer += 2;
    }
    else
    {
      strncpy(&iBPMwav[pointer],"n",1);
      pointer += 1;
      strncpy(&iBPMwav[pointer],temp_str,3);
      pointer += 3;
    }
    strncpy(&iBPMwav[pointer],".wav",4);
//  tmrpcm.play(iBPMwav);   
  }
}
```

Sketch uses 734 bytes (2%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32256 bytes. Global variables use 15 bytes (0%) of dynamic memory...

Comment: BTW: String use even more RAM than compiler can see. And String+String is awfully complicated, creating a lot of garbage  :)